# VSCode Vim Extension '*' search not properly searching whole words when '$' is taken out of Editor:WordSeparators

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VSCode configured with the Vim v1.24.3 and PHP v1.26.11793 extensions. I've removed the '$' from the Editor:WordSeparator string to allow PHP variables that begin with '$' to be seen as whole words. When I place my cursor on a variable and type '*' to search for other instances of that variable, the search is performed without the '>' termination that would enforce the whole word search. Therefore a search for `$foo` will find `$foobar` as well, as shown in this example:

[image: simple search]

Is there a settings parameter I can change to fix this so that the search is performed on the whole word `$foo`?